# How can I calculate average of limitless number of coordinates inputs?

Tags: python, coordinates

I am trying to write a code that finds middle point of multiple locations on the earth. I wrote the one with 3 coordinates, but i want to make it limitless.

If the inputs were just a normal integer or a float, it would be so easy to find average lots of them, but coordinates are seperated by a comma and you have to seperate and take latitude and longitude before you calculate average of them. This is the fact that makes it hard.

Here is the code with "3" coordinats:

```
cord_1 = input("Enter the Coordinates of First Point:")
cord_2 = input("Enter the Coordinates of Second Point:")
cord_3 = input("Enter the Coordinates of Third Point:")

c11 = float(cord_1.partition(",")[0])   
c12 = float(cord_1.partition(",")[-1])

c21 = float(cord_2.partition(",")[0])
c22 = float(cord_2.partition(",")[-1])   #These 6 lines seperates the coordinates by before comma and after comma,
                                         # (Which means longitude and latitude)
c31 = float(cord_3.partition(",")[0])
c32 = float(cord_3.partition(",")[-1])

mid_lon = str("{:.6f}".format(float((c11 + c21 + c31)/3)))   #These lines takes first 6 digits of average coordinate, NOT ROUND IT   
mid_lat = str("{:.6f}".format(float((c12 + c22 + c32)/3)))

print(mid_lon, mid_lat, sep =", ")                           #Reunions the latitude and longitude and prints it
```

Outputs:

```
Enter the Coordinats of First Point: 38.911203, 27.832993
Enter the Coordinats of Second Point: 38.916983, 27.819857
Enter the Coordinats of Third Point: 38.914627, 27.836506
38.914271, 27.829785
```

The code that i wrote might be a dead solution to problem, i am open to smarter solutions of course.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop to input the coordinates, like so.

Note that coordinates that are very far away from each other (esp. e.g. around the globe) will give you wrong results here, but the input stage is still fine.

```
# Input coordinates into a list

coords = []
while True:
    try:
        i = input(f"Enter the Coordinates of Point {len(coords) + 1}:").strip()
        if not i:  # An empty string breaks the loop
            break
        lon, _, lat = i.partition(",")
        coords.append((float(lon), float(lat)))
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Sorry, invalid input ({e})")

# Transpose the coordinate pairs [(a, b), (c, d), (e, f)] into [(a, c, e), (b, d, f)]
lons, lats = zip(*coords)

# Compute averages (NB: this does not take wrapping around the globe into account at all)
avg_lon = sum(lons) / len(lons)
avg_lat = sum(lats) / len(lats)

print(avg_lon, avg_lat, sep=", ")
```